# Angular add component dynamicaly to another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

This for me is super basic functionality that a FrontEnd framework should have.
But I wasn't able to find it in Angular.

I have this scenario:
One component does some request to an external service with an asynchronous call (in this example is a fake call), then based on the response (if the number is odd or even) this component adds to this view one component or another.

Consider this small example

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { of, merge, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements  OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  const subscribe = this.serverFakeCall().subscribe(
    val => {
      console.log("received value ", val);
      if (val%2 == 0) {
        // The OddComponent should be displayed
      } else {
        // The EvenComponent should be displayed
      }
    });
  }

  private serverFakeCall() : Observable<number>{
    const randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2))
    return of(randomNumber).pipe(delay(3000))
  }

}
```

Full code example avaliable here [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dtg8w](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dtg8w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**I want to add dynamically** `OddComponent` **or** `EvenComponent`
**I don't want to add both of them to the template and then 'hide' one or another with** `ngIf`

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: See this article https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286

Comment: No, it is not a super basic functionality for a framework. On the contrary, the framework, as a MVVM pattern, avoids doing thing like this in the old day with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This was not possible until Angular v9.

Now thanks to Ivy (the successor of the View Engine), the concept of *locality* is introduced and it is possible to lazy load components, that is you can *load* dynamically the components at runtime.

There is a [great article from Natanel Basal](https://netbasal.com/welcome-to-the-ivy-league-lazy-loading-components-in-angular-v9-e76f0ee2854a) explaining how to implement this.
One snippet from the article:

```
import { FooComponent } from './foo/foo.component';

@Component({
  template: `
    <button (click)="loadFoo()">Load FooComponent</button>
    <ng-container *ngIf="foo">
       <ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]="foo | async"></ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  foo: Promise<Type<FooComponent>>;

  loadFoo() {
    if (!this.foo) {
      this.foo = import(`./foo/foo.component`)
                       .then(({ FooComponent }) => FooComponent);
    }
  }
}
```

I would suggest to read the whole article to get all the details about it.